# How t wait while one process ended with ```boost::process```?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, process, boost-process

I have main program and system windows calculator. I want to run calculator from main prograM then wait while user close it and then give up control to the main program.

I try this solutions:

```
auto child = boost::process::child("calc.exe");
child.wait();
```

and

```
auto child = boost::process::child("calc.exe");
while (child.running()) {}
```

And in both ways calculator start but main process don't wait until the child closes and run farther.

How I should do this?

Comment: You'll need to use the `start /wait calc.exe` trick.  How to do that from boost::process::child is left as an exercise.

Comment: You seem to be waiting in right way. Probably `calc.exe` is just a launcher for the real calculator and your program actually progresses when it finishes

Comment: You are running on Windows 10. *calc.exe* isn't the Calculator application. It's a launcher that exits right after it launched Calculator.